# add_submenu_page doesn't display submenu if menu slug is the same as in top menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a top menu and a submenu, but to prevent duplicating top menu in the submenu, I'm setting the submenu `menu_slug` the same as in the top menu. Why the submenu is not displayed at all in this case?

```
add_action("admin_menu", "setup_theme_admin_menus");    

function setup_theme_admin_menus() {    
    add_menu_page('Theme settings', 'Example theme', 'manage_options',   
        'tut_theme_settings', 'theme_settings_page');  

    add_submenu_page('tut_theme_settings',   
        'Front Page Elements', 'Front Page', 'manage_options',   
        'tut_theme_settings', 'theme_front_page_settings');   
}      

// Handler to top level menu
function theme_settings_page() {  
}  

function theme_front_page_settings() {
    echo "Some text of submenu page";  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That's the default behavior, see the [`$menu_slug` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Parameters) for `add_submenu_page`:

> If you want to NOT duplicate the parent menu item, you need to set the name of the `$menu_slug` exactly the same as the parent slug.

The problem is that putting the same slug **merges** the callback for the menu and the submenu.

---

You may need to manipulate the global `$submenu` variable to achieve your goal, note that I gave a different slug to the submenu:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'setup_theme_admin_menus' );    

function setup_theme_admin_menus() 
{    
    add_menu_page(
        'Theme settings', 
        'Example theme', 
        'manage_options',   
        'tut_theme_settings', 
        'theme_settings_page'
    );  

    add_submenu_page(
        'tut_theme_settings',       // parent slug
        'Front Page Elements 2',    // page title
        'Front Page 2',             // menu title
        'manage_options',           // capability
        'tut_theme_settings2',      // slug
        'theme_front_page_settings' // callback
    );  

    // REMOVE THE SUBMENU CREATED BY add_menu_page
    global $submenu;
    unset( $submenu['tut_theme_settings'][0] );
}
```

Comment: I didn't understands you. What's wrong with my code, I use the same menu_slug as for parent and why submenu is not displayed at all.

Comment: @Oleg, what you are trying **will not work**. You will know why if you `echo` something in the function `theme_settings_page()`. As far as I can tell (and I did lots of tests), the only way to solve this is giving different slugs and manipulating the `global $submenu`.